# ASP.NET GridView/ListView Print Functionality

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to give users an ability to print asp.net gridview/listview report. Could anyone please guide me how it's best achieved?

Ability to export to Excel/PDF would be good as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a print stylesheet that strips out everything you don't want on the page.

Have a javascript print button for printing the page.

Job done.